# Protractor module protractor-retry tests will not re-run and get Microsoft JScript compilation error when running on desktop

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests, e2e

I am using protractor-retry version 2.0.1 and after the tests run I get this error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5SLH.png)

I cannot find any leads so that is why I am reaching out here. One of my co-workers gets the same error.

It's failing to run this command (same as what initiates the first run). Of course when I run npm run e2e in the terminal it works.

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run e2e" terminated with exit code: 1.

Here's some logging info:

```
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Scott Floyd\projects\site2\st-site
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "e2e"
23 verbose node v14.16.1
24 verbose npm  v6.14.12
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error st-site@0.0.0 e2e: `ng e2e iccmNA-e2e`
27 error Exit status 1
```

Any tips would be helpful, my google searches are coming up with posts circa 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete the *node_modules* folder and reinstall all dependencies with `npm i`

Comment: No luck. It seems like the testing community is losing interest in protractor. Cypress might be the way to go.